# bash scripting on returning values from functions

Tags: bash, scripting, scripting-language

I have a bash method that looks like this

```
function getServiceId() {
    serviceId=$(docker -H $1 ps -qf label=com.docker.swarm.service.name=$2)
    $3=serviceId
    return 0
}
```

I execute this function like this

```
getServiceId $node1 $service1 retVal
```

The error comes from line `$3=serviceId`. 
It tries to execute the the value of serviceId on bash thinking it is a bash command. My goal is to return the value in the variable serviceId.
How do I do that?

Comment: You miss `$` for variable `$serviceId`, but  `printf -v $3 "$serviceId"` could be your way... see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43644421/1765658)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getServiceId() {
    local serviceId
    read serviceId  < <(
        docker -H $1 ps -qf label=com.docker.swarm.service.name=$2
    )
    printf -v $3 "%s" "$serviceId"
}

getServiceId $node1 $service1 retVal
```

This will work fine for **this** specific case. But I like to use `read` for setting variable for a lot of thing like:

```
{ read foo ; read device total use free prct mpoint } < <(df -k /)
echo $use
```

or

```
# Work on DB
while IFS=$'\t' read id name label ;do
    [ "$id" ] && (( id > 100 )) && {
         # Doing something for entries with id > 100 ...
    }
done < <(
    sqlclient "SELECT id,name,label FROM ..."
)
```

But care: by default `read` will *interpret* backslashes `\` as *escape char* (wiping a newline, for example). see `help read`:

> ```
> read: read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
>    Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.
>
>    Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
>    if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
>    splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
>    word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
>    the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
>    delimiters.
>
>    If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable.
>
>    Options:
>      -a array assign the words read to sequential indices of the array
>           variable ARRAY, starting at zero
>      -d delim continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather
>           than newline
>      -e       use Readline to obtain the line in an interactive shell
>      -i text  Use TEXT as the initial text for Readline
>      -n nchars    return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting
>           for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than NCHARS
>           characters are read before the delimiter
>      -N nchars    return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
>           EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter
>      -p prompt    output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
>           attempting to read
>      -r       do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
>      -s       do not echo input coming from a terminal
>      -t timeout   time out and return failure if a complete line of input is
>           not read within TIMEOUT seconds.  The value of the TMOUT
>           variable is the default timeout.  TIMEOUT may be a
>           fractional number.  If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns immediately,
>           without trying to read any data, returning success only if
>           input is available on the specified file descriptor.  The
>           exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded
>      -u fd        read from file descriptor FD instead of the standard input
>
>    Exit Status:
>    The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out
>    (in which case it's greater than 128), a variable assignment error occurs,
>    or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.
> ```

Comment: yes that is a Q i also have, I simply did this and it works, is it sth incorrect to do?
printf -v $3 "%s" $(docker -H $1 ps -qf label=com.docker.swarm.service.name=$2)

Comment: @curiousengineer Quote the subshell but yes that is fine.

Comment: @123, what do u mean quote the subshell. Not getting it and what is the issue if i dont?

Comment: @curiousengineer `"$(subshell stuff)"` The same thing it does if you quote variables, preserves a literal string.

Comment: Using `read` like this subjects the output of the process substitution to backslash interpretation and word splitting, i.e., resets all whitespace. Not sure what the benefit is supposed to be.

Comment: @F.Hauri So what's the benefit then? Why make it so it only works one specific case?

Comment: @123 I like to use `read` because of the very large potential you could obtain (upto binary read). See `while IFS=$'\t' read id name label ;do ... ;done < <(sql "SELECT id,name,label...")...` for sample

Comment: @F.Hauri Think somethings been lost in translation, I have no idea what  `very large potential you could obtain` is supposed to mean.

Comment: @123 `read` let you interpret *escape* character (`\`) or not, could use *timeout*, set many different variables at once, and a lot of things... upto read binary.

Comment: @F.Hauri You aren't actually *using* any of those special features, and pointing them out has *no* relevance to the question as asked. Just use `serviceID=$(docker ...)`.

Comment: @chepner The syntax you propose *could suffice*, but learning *good practices* could be nice too! Syntax `read < <(...)` has quite same performance no more forks, is clearer and more scalable... And for the *relevance* I will let you re-read the **title** of this question. At all, I don't understand why my answer could be bad?

Answer (score -1):

Simply capture the STDOUT of the `getServiceId` function.

```
function getServiceId() {
    docker -H "$1" ps -qf "label=com.docker.swarm.service.name=$2"
}

serviceId="$(getServiceId "arg1" "arg2")"
echo "Service ID is $serviceId"
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't return values from functions in shell; you write to standard output, or set global variables. (No one ever said shell promoted good software engineering practice.)

```
getServiceId () {
    docker -H "$1" ps -qf label=com.docker.swarm.service.name="$2"
}

serviceID=$(getServiceID)
```

or

```
getServiceID () {
    serviceID=$(docker -H "$1" ps -qf label=com.docker.swarm.service.name="$2")
}
```